# Canonical module of rees algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

[Example 4.27, Integral Closure, Rees Algebras, Multiplicities, Algorithms] by Vasconcelos, says that if $I=(f_1,\ldots,f_g)$ is an ideal generated by a regular sequence  with $g\ge 2$ then the canonical module of the Rees algebra $S=R[It]$ is $\bigoplus\limits_{n\ge 1}I^{n-g+1}\omega_Rt^n$. But its proof is in a paper of Bruns which is unfortunately unavailable. My main question is that does this result hold without any assumption on $R$, e.g. the Cohen-Macaulayness of $R$?

Comment: What is $n$?  The dimension of $R$?  Regardless, I'm sure you can figure out the canonical module from this paper which looks at a much more general situation.  *Filtered rings, Filtered Blowing-Ups and normal two-dimensional singularities with "star-shaped" resolution* by Tomari and Watanabe.  See in particular section 3 (Corollary 3.3(ii)).  This paper handles more general Rees algebras (such as symbolic Rees algebras) as well.

Answer (score 2):

The result of Bruns needed for determining the canonical module of the Rees algebra with respect to an ideal generated by a regular sequence is Theorem 8.8 in Bruns and Vetter, *Determinantal Rings*. This assumes that the ground ring is a Cohen-Macaulay normal domain.
A more general frame can be found in the paper *[On the divisor class group of Rees-algebras](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869385901826)* (Theorem (c)) of Herzog and Vasconcelos.